# Downloading a file with UnityWebRequest

Tags: unity, server

I need to download a file (a .ogv video) from a server using a UnityWebRequest.

Let's say the file is located at `home/folder1/folder2/file.ogv` on the server, and the IP adress of the server is `1.2.3.4`. I tried to create my web request with:

```
webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("1.2.3.4/home/folder1/folder2/file.ogv");
```

However when this web request is sent, nothing happens.

```
webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("1.2.3.4/home/folder1/folder2/file.ogv");
DownloadHandler receiveBundle = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
webRequest.downloadHandler = receiveBundle;
webRequest.Send();
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. The previous error message was due to a typo.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the file from a web browser? The most likely reason you can't access it from Unity is because it's not accessible at all.

Comment: You were right, I put my files in another server and something happened (meaning some files were downloaded this time). However, I still have a problem as the downloaded files are all 1kB. Should I edit my answer to reflect this?

Comment: Can you post the full log? any error or response you are getting from request you made?